# Why text in a td can't be flush with the top and bottom of the td edges?

Tags: html, css

I have the tr and td showing padding and margin = 0. I have some text in the td. I set the background of the tr to yellow so I can see the edges. I can see 3 pixels of empty space above the characters and 3 pixels below the characters. The top and bottom of the text are not flush with the td edges.

Is this something I don't have control over?

[See JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/xUeXz/)

Comment: It happens in all the browsers

Answer (score 3):

Try using `line-height`, here's your example forked:

http://jsfiddle.net/TdbEe/1/